# Validating Attributes of Attributes in Python

Tags: python, class, validation, oop, pydantic

I am working on a project which requires extensive validation. So far I have several classes inheriting from pydantic.BaseModel, and I have several validation strategies for initialization and attr reassignment each one of them, and they all worked well. Nevertheless, these classes are interdependent, and their validation should be based one on another.

My dataclasses are, for instance (only two in these example):

```py
class Dimensions(BaseModel):

    model_config = ConfigDict(
        validate_assignment=True,
        extra="forbid"
        )


    number_of_nodes: int = Field(gt=0)
    number_of_elements: int = Field(gt=0)
    # ... several other attrs
    # ...
    # validations for Dimensions class



class Problem(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        validate_assignment=True,
        extra="forbid"
        )
    
    name: str
    number_of_layers: int = Field(gt=0)
    # ... several other attrs
    # ...
    # validations for Problem class
```

My problem is: several parameters from Problem should be validated using Dimensions, not only when instantiated, but also when assigned.

My strategy was: create a new class to validate these classes together. I am sharing two ideas below, but feel free to provide anything you think it is better.

I have managed solving this problem through inheritance. Here is my solution:

```py
class Settings(Dimensions, Problem, BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        validate_assignment=True,
        extra="forbid"
        )

    # name: str
    # number_of_layers: int = Field(gt=0)

    @model_validator(mode='after')
    def dummy_check_n_layers(self) -> 'Settings':
        if self.number_of_layers > self.number_of_elements:
            raise ValueError(
                "number_of_layers cannot be bigger than number_of_elements"
            )
        if (self.number_of_layers - 1) > self.number_of_nodes:
            raise ValueError(
                "number_of_slices cannot be bigger than number_of_nodes"
            )
        return self


s = Settings(number_of_nodes=10, number_of_elements=20, name="test", number_of_layers=5)

s.number_of_layers = 20 # throws Validation error successfully
```

However, I have many parameters for each dataclass, and for a matter of syntax and organisation, I would prefer to not inherit directly, and instead do something like this:

```py
class Settings(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(
        validate_assignment=True,
        extra="forbid"
        )

    problem: Problem
    dimensions: Dimensions


    @model_validator(mode='after')
    def dummy_check_n_layers(self) -> 'Settings':
        if self.problem.number_of_layers > self.dimensions.number_of_elements:
            raise ValueError(
                "number_of_layers cannot be bigger than number_of_elements"
            )
        if (self.problem.number_of_layers - 1) > self.dimensions.number_of_nodes:
            raise ValueError(
                "number_of_slices cannot be bigger than number_of_nodes"
            )
        return self


d = Dimensions(number_of_nodes=10, number_of_elements=20,)
p = Problem(name="test", number_of_layers=5)
s = Settings(problem=p, dimensions=d)

s.problem.number_of_layers = 20 # does not throw an error
```

Is there any way we could validate when assigning an attribute of an attribute? If not, do you have any other ideas to go about this validation scheme?

I hope that describes well my problem.

Cheers :}